# Initialize a 2D string array and print it

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, initialization

I'm learning C for fun and I'm trying to make a program that creates a array of strings. I'm trying this right now:

```
char str[2][10];
strcpy(str[0], "foo");
strcpy(str[1], "bar");
printf("%d \n",str[0]);
printf("%d \n",str[1]);
```

But my *`printf`* returns only some numbers, and I would like it to display *foo* and *bar*. I've been reading about and I think that it is displaying a pointer to my strings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it displaying?

Comment: You might want to spend a little time looking at the `printf` and format string documentation.

Comment: You have a ***1D***-string array, which in fact is a *2D*-**`char`** array. (I adjusted the title accordingly)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you guys with such na amateur mistake. I edited the title to make it match with the text.
Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are printing using the format `%d`, which is used to print an `int`. Modify your code to :

```
printf("%s\n", str[0]);
printf("%s\n", str[1]);
```

See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for more information on the specifiers' format for `printf`.